# Access REST API protected with Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

Here is my configuration (using Spring Security 3.2.5):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter userPassAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
        http.addFilterAfter(userPassAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

and here are my bean configurations:

```
@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        List providers = new LinkedList();
        providers.add(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        ProviderManager pm = new ProviderManager(providers);
        return pm;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        return new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter restApiAuthenticationFilter() {
        MyAuthFilter filter = new MyAuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        filter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));

        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setUseReferer(true);
        return successHandler;
    }
```

where MyAuthFilter is as follows:

```
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //do my job here related to setting some custom header on request.
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        //check for my header and authenticate if this is the case, otherwise, call super.
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }

}
```

and MyAuthenticationEntryPoint is as follows:

```
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I access some of my rest api what I have put on my hand, I get as follows:

```
curl -i -H "auth_header: a_token_value_here" http://myhost:8080/path/api/list_users
```

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
auth_header: a_token_value_here
Location: http://myhost:8080/path/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 13:01:24 GMT
```

As you can see, I can't get to the requested REST API due to the fact that Spring does not let me to get there. After Spring checks that I'm authenticated it simply stops to redirect me, and instead sends a redirect status response, what if I access I get the same again. **Can anybody guide me how to get through Spring Security to REST API, using this kind of approach?**

Comment: Have you tried it from browser as well? I guess it's unable to maintain session.

Comment: @PramodKarandikar I'm not interested to make it available from browser. I need this REST API to be accessed by a client via a `JavaScript` based framework or something similar. Yes, you are right, it's unable to maintain session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit messed up, but here are some pointers:

1. You have `.httpBasic()` in your config. Do you use HTTP Basic as authentication method? If not, remove.
2. You base your authentication filter on `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. That is for web browser form authentication. Maybe you want to use `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` as super class instead.
3. `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is for stateful, session-based login. It is likely this causes the redirect. Remove.